# Node too slow if ran from terminal

Tags: node.js

I've noticed that for some reason when I try to run a node script in terminal it's much slower than same statement in PHP no matter what.

test.js:

```
console.log("test");
```

duration @ ubuntu:

```
aherne@aherne-NUC8i7INH:~$ time node test.js
real    0m0,317s
user    0m0,303s
sys 0m0,016s
```

test.php:

```
echo "test\n";
```

duration @ ubuntu:

```
aherne@aherne-NUC8i7INH:~$ time php test.php
real    0m0,096s
user    0m0,021s
sys 0m0,028s
```

Am I doing something wrong or node is that slow? DISCLAIMER: I'm a beginner in node (obviously)

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to benchmark here? The startup times of each executable?

Obviously `node` is far more complex and has a higher startup time.

It is a very bad test since this is not what happens when `php` or `node` processes a user request - as the process will already be running.

Comment: I want to create a library in node whose I/O are from terminal. PHP delegates to node for HTML templating then receives a response that will be outputted to user. This way all frontend (view) incl. templating will be entirely controlled from JS... Maybe a better idea is to start a node server listening on a port then all communication will be done on that port? This avoids starting node on every request

Comment: Absolutely. Otherwise you will pay the compilation at each request.

Answer (score 0):

Reason was ancient node version (10.19.0). After upgrading to v16.14.0 everything worked instantly:

```
aherne@aherne-NUC8i7INH:~$ time node test.js
real    0m0,057s
user    0m0,045s
sys 0m0,013s
```